# Many to Many relation in Entity Framework doesn't retrieve the related collections

Tags: entity-framework, orm, ef-code-first, mapping

I'm trying to map many to many SQL relation in Entity Framework using code first.

Here are my classes:

> [Table("B3_360ViewerData")]
>
> ```
> public class ViewerData : Entity
>  {
>      //.... Other properties ...//
>
>      // The navigation property
>      public EntityCollection<Feature> Features { get; set; }
> ```
>
> }
>
> [Table("B3_Feature")]
>
> public class Feature : Entity
>      {
>
> ```
>    //.... Other properties ...//
>    // The navigation property
>    public ICollection<ViewerData> ViewerData { get; set; }
> ```
>
> }
>
> CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ViewerDataFeatures](
>
> [Feature_Id] [int] NULL,
>
> [ViewerData_Id] [int] NULL
>
> )

The insertion in this table went well like I expected, but when I want to retrieve the ViewerData entity i don't get Features collection populated it is null.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why do you mix `EntityCollection` and `ICollection`? I'd try `ICollection` for both collections.

Comment: It doesn't matter because `EntityCollection` implements `ICollection`

Comment: Do you include the `Features` when you load the `ViewerData`, like `context.ViewerDatas.Include(v => v.Features)...`?